# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aws_cdk'

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I am trying to use `aws_cdk` in my project.
I am using visual studio as a IDE and I setup my `virtualenv` doing this:

1. Install https://nodejs.org/en/.
2. Through npm, install cdk from cmd window: `npm install -g aws-cdk`
3. Install python3
4. Using terminal in Visual Studio Code: go to the project folder
5. Run `python -m venv .venv` to create the virtual env.
6. Activate it: `source .venv/bin/activate`
7. Run pip install: `pip install -r requirements.txt`
8. Run another pip install: `pip install -r requirements-dev.txt`.
9. Check with `cdk diff` in the cmd

This last step returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:......\app.py", line 4, in <module>
    import aws_cdk as cdk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aws_cdk'
```

My `App.py` looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

import aws_cdk as cdk

import module_config

from myproject.myproject_stack import MyStack

app = cdk.App()

tags = module_config.with_tags(service_name="my_project")
prefix = module_config.with_prefix(service_name="my_project")
MyStack(
    app,
    construct_id=prefix,
    prefix=prefix,
    tags=tags,
    env=module_config.env,
)
app.synth()
```

My `requirements.txt` looks like:

```
aws-cdk-lib==2.56.1
constructs>=10.0.0,<11.0.0
```

The `requirement-dev.txt` is:

```
bandit>=1.7.4
black>=22.10.0
coverage>=6.4.4
pylint==2.15.5
pytest
pytest-cov
yamllint
pre-commit
```

If in the vistual studio I do `ctrl+mouse click` it opens the `aws-cdk` code, therefore I know it is installed, but seems like the virtual env is not able to find it.
In my local repository, the folder `.venv` has a folder `Lib\site-packages` and this one has another called `aws_cdk`.

I see everything corret, but when running the `cdk diff` it breaks.

Comment: You used npm install.  Not sure if python actually reads npm stuff.  I'd though it'd be ```python -m pip install aws-cdk``` or something similar?

Comment: @ewokx in the requirement.txt I install aws-cdk-lib which is the library

Comment: Could you run the following command and give the output: `npm install --silent -g aws-cdk && which cdk && cdk --version && npm uninstall --silent -g aws-cdk`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. Windows CDK do not use virtualenv. This means that despite setting up a venv, the code will fail because nodejs is installed globally. Therefore you need to install pyhon cdk lib globally.

I tested it in other laptops and the issue was replicated. Once I tested using powershell and WSL everything worked as intended.

Comment: Windows CDK does use the virtualenv. Check your cdk.json file. If the second line is   `"app": "python3 app.py"` try changing to `"app": "python app.py"` and then run again in the virtualenv